# Angular2 creating new instance of input value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a grand parent component in which i am passing "selectedValue" to parent component as below :-
Code in Grand Parent Template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'grand-parent',
  template: '<parent [details]="selectedValue" ></parent>'
})
export class GrandParentComponent implements OnInit  {
    private selectedValue = 0 ;
    ngOnInit() {
     setTimeout(function() {
      this.selectedValue =+ 1;
      }, 1000);
    }
}
```

In my parent component i am using a loop to create a child component and passing the "selectedValue" like below:-

```
<template ngFor let-tab [ngForOf]="arry" let-i="index">
   <child [details]="selectedValue"></child>
// some more logic
</template>
```

The problem is the child component is taking the last value of selectedValue.
For example if i pass the selectedValue as 1, 2, 3.
Then in child component i will receive details = 3 for all the three child components as i am iterating.
I need to some how pass the current "selectedValue" to their respected child component 
Ex for selectedValue as 1, 2, 3. i want something like

```
<child [details]='1'></child>
<child [details]='2'></child>
<child [details]='3'></child>
```

Not like

```
<child [details]='3'></child>
<child [details]='3'></child>
<child [details]='3'></child>
```

Some thing like a new object for every "selectedValue".
How to achive this any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to provide more code for us to see what's going on. The code should demonstrate where `selectedValue` comes from. If you use `ngFor` and don't use the `tab` variable you introduce in `*ngFor`, then you can't expect to get different values passed.

Comment: You could use the more convenient `<ng-container *ngFor="let tab of arry; let i=index">` instead of `<template ngFor let-tab [ngForOf]="arry" let-i="index">`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I am using "tab" for doing some logic, which is not related with the post. Only thing related is how to pass selectedValue in child component so that it should be fixed for each child component. All the child components should not take the last passed value of "selectedValue"

Comment: Still " The code should demonstrate where `selectedValue` comes from."

Comment: selectedValue is being passed from grandparent

Comment: The added code looks quite weird. What is this `setTimeout()` supposed to do? I still can't see from your code how `selectedValue` can become `3`.

Comment: I just wanted to show you how i am getting selectedValue changed. The motive of this post is to retain the selectedValue for each child component.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for one-time binding. There is no such thing in Angular2. `[details]="selectedValue"` is a binding that updates `details` whenever `selectedValue` changes. What you might want is to make `selectedValue` an array as large as `arry` and then use `[details]="selectedValue[i]"` so each child is bound to a different value.

Comment: ok thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

This might not or not fully answer your question but

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    this.selectedValue =+ 1;
  }, 1000);
```

should be

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.selectedValue =+ 1;
  }, 1000);
```

otherwise `this.selectedValue` won't reference the `selectedValue` in your components class.

Comment: Yes you are right, i typed it wrongly as i was in hurry to answer your question.

Comment: And this fully solves your problem? Didn't expect that :D